# Como inserir dados e uma tabela com Foreign Key no PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

eu tenho 2 tabelas Cliente e Endereço com relacionamento 1,1

Na tabela endereço tem a FK.

Qual seria o jeito certo de fazer o insert nessas tabelas, relacionando cliente com endereço?

Imagino que LastInsertId não seria viável em um sistema muito grande com vários registros sendo relizados ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Wellington edite sua pergunta  e coloque junto o seu código

Comment: Não era para ser ao contrário? O Cliente ter a chave estrangeira do endereco?

Comment: O ideal aqui no fórum é que você coloque seu código para que possamos te ajudar melhor. Pergunta respondida com as informações que colocou, se colocar mais informações e ela não for compatível com a situação eu edito/removo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal é que o cliente receba a chave estrangeira do endereço e não o contrário. 
Você pode usar o [mysqli_insert_id()](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php) ou [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php), pois mesmo que tenham várias pessoas criando cadastro ao mesmo tempo, o SGBD vai cuidar desse problema para você.

Cada cliente cria uma conexão ao banco. Pelo manual do próprio MySQL: O ID que é gerado ao usar esse comando no servidor é gerado com base na conexão. Isso quer dizer que o valor retornado pela função por um cliente específico é o primeiro valor AUTO_INCREMENT gerado  pelo mais recente comando daquele cliente
 que afete uma coluna AUTO_INCREMENT e esse valor não pode ser afetador por outros clientes, mesmo que eles gerem outros valores de AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Coloquei a chave estrangeira do lado errado realmente, mas a questão era realmente saber se o ideal era usar o mysqli_insert_id() ou PDO::lastInsertId(). Será que se um cliente inserir registros ao mesmo tempo de outro isso não pode dar problema? Porque? Gostaria de saber o motivo

Comment: @wellington adicionei essa informação nos comentários. Espero que agora esclareça melhor :D